# Visual Studio Code File not outputting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

So i have made a simple Program that outputs the text "Hi!" in C++.
I'm using Visual Studio Code and it was working before. But the last time i tried to open the program after succesfully compiling it, it wanted me to choose a software to open the file. I accedentally chose QT, and deinstalled QT afterwards, because i didn't want it anyways and thought that might fix the problem. But no there is no output in the terminal.

Here is a screenshot of VS Code after trying to output the file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiu5G.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently typing test.cpp in the terminal. This is the source code of the program and not the executable.

You should type `test.exe` in the terminal.